# Why non-mutable lambda captures can be moved?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, move-semantics

AFAIK non-mutable lambdas capture variables as const. This makes me wonder why can they still be moved?

```
auto p = std::make_unique<int>(0);
auto f = [p = std::move(p)](){ p->reset(); }; // Error, p is const
auto f2 = std::move(f); // OK, the pointer stored inside lambda is moved
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> AFAIK non-mutable lambdas capture variables as const.

No, they do not. Their `operator()` overloads are `const`. The actual member variables aren't.

It's no different from:

```
class A
{
  unique_ptr<int> p
public:
  //Insert constructors here.

  void operator() const {p->reset();}
};
```